# Working with .net core and mongodb understanding the performance

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, .net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

This is the first time when I have .net core and MongoDB usually use Entity Framework ORM.
I use .net core 3 and MongoDB driver 2.11 to work with the database.

Here is an example of a repository service:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : IDocument
{
    private readonly IMongoCollection<T> _collection;

    public Repository(IDatabaseSettings settings)
    {
            var client = new MongoClient(settings.ConnectionString);
            var database = client.GetDatabase(settings.DatabaseName);
            _collection = database.GetCollection<T>(GetCollectionName(typeof(T)));
    }

    Task<T> FindOneAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filterExpression){}
    Task<T> FindByIdAsync(string id){}
    Task InsertOneAsync(T document) {}
    Task InsertManyAsync(ICollection<T> documents){}
    Task ReplaceOneAsync(T document) {}
    Task DeleteOneAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filterExpression){}
    Task DeleteByIdAsync(string id) {}
    Task DeleteManyAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filterExpression){}
    
}
```

As you can see this is a standard definition of repository class.

My question is when the repository works with a specific collection does all collection is loaded to local memory?

For example, if I want to find a specific document in the collection,
then GetCollection in constructor fetching collection from database and
running on all documents in the collection locally?

Or does it generate a query and execute it in a database similarly to Entity Framework ORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is when the repository works with a specific collection does all collection is loaded to local memory?

No.

It just takes a "handle" to the collection. It does **not** fetch any document.

> For example, if I want to find a specific document in the collection, then GetCollection in constructor fetching collection from database and running on all documents in the collection locally?

Neither.

You would need to use `FindOne` or `FindById`. **Those** will issue a query to fetch documents (one for that matter)

btw you may want a `Find` as well (thus to get more than only one doc)

> Or does it generate a query and execute it in a database similarly to Entity Framework ORM?

`GetCollection` does not generate a query to fetch anything

---

It seems a bit "authoritative" so you may just open a mongo shell and play around:

```
// just set up some data to collection dummy
> db.dummy.insert([{a:2},{a:1}])
// look for any document having field 'a' with value 1.
// only one doc returned, fair enough
> db.dummy.find({ a: 1 })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60334ea3623e06e621f86a0b"), "a" : 1 }

// this is equivalent to
> db.getCollection('dummy').find({ a: 1 })
// without the find() you just get information on the collection, NO documents fetched
// imagine collection as an object, on which you can issue queries (find, findOne, remove, ...)
// but not necessarily query to touch documents: e.g ensureIndex, help, ...
// (just type <<tab>> to see available commands)
> db.getCollection('dummy')
dummy.dummy
```

As a side note, `getCollection` allows to target collection names with namings a bit peculiar like

```
db._dummy.insert({ a: 1 }) // fails because of '_' char
uncaught exception: TypeError: db._dummy is undefined :
db.getCollection('_dummy').insert({ a: 1 })
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```